# php/mysql search and replace a parts of a sentence

Tags: php, mysql

Replacing parts of a sentence in mysql table using php.I need help in getting this done rightly. eg. replacing http://www.gettingthingsdone.com/products/electronics with http://www.gettingthingsdone.com/electronics

```
$sql = "UPDATE ".$table_name."
                        SET ".$val." = '".$SearchAndReplace_replace_with."'
                        WHERE ".$val." LIKE '"."%".$SearchAndReplace_search_term."%"."'";
```

Comment: Why don't you create a backup on your table then try it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider to use [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) of mysql that is designed what are you looking for. before executing the command take the backup of table.

```
   UPDATE [your_table_name] SET [your_table_field] = REPLACE([your_table_field],
 '[string_to_find]' , '[string_to_be_replaced]')
```

Comment: thanks pal. this is what i did. seems i'm having problems with concatinating. sql = "UPDATE ".$table_name."
                            SET ".$val." = '".$SearchAndReplace_replace_with."'
                            WHERE ".$val." LIKE '"."%".$SearchAndReplace_search_term."%"."'";
                            REPLACE "(.$val '$SearchAndReplace_search_term' , '$SearchAndReplace_replace_with')

Comment: @karto: you can not mix WHERE and REPLACE. Try this `$sql = "UPDATE ".$table_name." SET ".$val." = REPLACE(".$val.",'".$SearchAndReplace_replace_with."','".$SearchAndReplace_replace_with."')"; `